# automatically enter shell command

Tags: shell, scripting, adb

I would like to know how to enter shell commands automatically!!
I don't know if I'm breaking my question well, I'll try to describe my problem.

I am working on the automation of a task with ADB (Android Debug Bridge), I would like after typing the **adb shell** command, another command like **cd /data/** to be typed automatically in my shell.
is it possible to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by automatically ? Do you mean a script in which you can put multiple commands ?

Comment: yes !!!
but the problem is that once the ADB shell is open, the other commands are executed in the terminal, not in the adb shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's quite simple!

Solution:
[image: Solution]

```
(
  echo cd /data/system/
  echo command 1
  echo command 2
  echo reboot
)
```

Comment: Please do not post text in a screen shot, instead copy the text and paste it into your answer.

Comment: no need for pipe: `adb shell "cd /data/system; command 1; command 2; reboot"`